# Redirect all apps traffic to socks proxy

Tags: linux, java, socks-proxy

I have a java app which needs to connect to company's resources. Those resources are only accessible through a development machine in that cluster. I'm working on a desktop.

Using SOCKS proxy I redirect traffic to the dev machine, which does the actual request in corp cluster. Currently, I have to setup every program's connection to use SOCKS proxy and change code.

Is it possible to start java process (this is java app) so **all** connections go through SOCKS proxy? Other apps on my desktop shouldn't be affected, only for this particular app which I'm working on (that later supposed to run in the corp cluster).